# How can i access to any data that is in private section of class?

Tags: c++, class, private

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int ID;
    string name;

public:
    Test(int ID, string name);
};

Test::Test(int ID, string name)
{
    this->ID = ID;
    this->name = name;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Test *> test_vect;

    Test *ptr = new Test(100, "John");

    test_vect.push_back(ptr);

    cout << ptr->ID << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is a simple code I'm trying.

I want to access to the data that I stored in vector.

I thought it would be accessible by using `->` just like vector of struct but I can't. So I want to know how to load the data in class.

In addition, I thought sending data to heap section using `new` would make it accessible at any  time I want regardless of whether it is private or public, but it seems like it is not possible.

Can you explain how it works?

(I don't even fully understand how `class` work, so detailed explanation would be very appreciated. Thx!)

Comment: What do you think `private` means?

Comment: Things in the `private` section are only accessible to the class itself.  Things in the `protected` section are also accessible to derived classes.  Things in the `public` section are accessible to everything.  Typically, an *accessor* member function is used to access private member variables.  `int getID() const { return ID; }`

Comment: Side note, you do not need pointers, nor `new` in your code.

Comment: [Simple tutorial on encapsulation in OOP](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-for-beginners-what-is-encapsulation/) (yes, it's java, but you'll get the point)

Comment: @Eljay Not only the class itself but also [frends](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) of the class can access private things.

Comment: Thank you all for answering. So to get to the point, I can't print or compare the data it contains unless it is done by function in its own class?

Comment: Correct, you can't print or compare the data in the `private` section unless it is done by a function in its own class, or a friend function.

Comment: You can access a private member by moving it to a public section or declaring the member public.

Answer (score 1):

A `private` variable cannot be accessed by code outside the class definition. (There are exceptions with `friend`)

`ptr->ID` does not work because `main` is outside the class definition.

This can be fixed by using a getter method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int _ID;
    string _name;

public:
    int ID() {return _ID;}
    string name() {return _name;}
    Test(int param_ID, string param_name);
};

Test::Test(int param_ID, string param_name)
{
    _ID = param_ID;
    _name = param_name;
}

int main()
{
    vector<Test *> test_vect;

    Test *ptr = new Test(100, "John");

    test_vect.push_back(ptr);

    cout << ptr->ID() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above example shows the getter methods `ID()` and `name()` which return the data members `_ID` and `_name` respectively.

`ID()` is allowed to access `_ID` because `ID()` is part of the class definition. `name()` is allowed to access `_name` because `name()` is part of the class definition.

Note: I would still consider this code to be flawed because it creates a new object on the heap, but does not delete it. You should also look up the keywords `new` and `delete` to see how they operate together.